# '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]

Tags: c, compilation, printf, sizeof

I keep getting compile warnings but I don't know how to fix it:

```
'%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int' [
```

The program runs fine but I still get the compile warnings:

```
/* Sizeof.c--Program to tell byte size of the C variable */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("\nA Char is %d bytes", sizeof( char ));
    printf("\nAn int is %d bytes", sizeof( int ));
    printf("\nA short is %d bytes", sizeof( short ));
    printf("\nA long is %d bytes", sizeof( long ));
    printf("\nA long long is %d bytes\n", sizeof( long long ));
    printf("\nAn unsigned Char is %d bytes", sizeof( unsigned char ));
    printf("\nAn unsigned int is %d bytes", sizeof( unsigned int));
    printf("\nAn unsigned short is %d bytes", sizeof( unsigned short ));
    printf("\nAn unsigned long is %d bytes", sizeof( unsigned long ));
    printf("\nAn unsigned long long is %d bytes\n",
            sizeof( unsigned long long ));
    printf("\nfloat is %d bytes", sizeof( float ));
    printf("\nA double is %d bytes\n", sizeof( double ));
    printf("\nA long double is %d bytes\n", sizeof( long double ));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: replace `%d` with `%ld`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`sizeof` returns `size_t` you need to use `%zu` for the format string instead of `%d`. The type of *unsigned integer* of `size_t` can vary (depending on platform) and may not be *long unsigned int* everywhere, which is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.5.3.4` *The sizeof operator* paragraph *4*:

> The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type)
>   is size_t, defined in  (and other headers).

Also note that using the wrong format specifier for `printf` is undefined behavior, which is covered in section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function*, which also covers `printf` with respect to format specifiers says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

**Update**

`Visual Studio` [does not support the `z` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tcxf1dw6.aspx):

> The hh, j, z, and t length prefixes are not supported.

the correct format specifier in this case would be `%Iu`.

Comment: In GCC 4.8.1 on Windows I get error: "unknown conversion type character 'z' in format" when printf'ing %zu.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak updated answer, probably related.

Comment: Thanks Shafik. Unfortunately none of this is cross platform. I have to cast size_t to (unsigned long) for the code to work on both Linux and Windows. On Linux when using %Iu (I as Integer) getting error "format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’".

Comment: @CzarekTomczak you are probably better off using an `ifdef` based on the OS to set  a format specifier variable and use that instead.

Comment: For now I will just stick with the cast, as this is only some debugging info, it's not that important. But I will keep it in my mind on how to do it the right way in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: I was following a cprogrammingtutorial.pdf and I ran into this same error. Your resolution above fixed the issue, I am on Linux so I used %zu and it worked

Comment: @meanbunny I am not familiar with that document,  It may be helpful to notify the author so it could be fixed eventually.

Answer (score 10):

The compiler is warning you that you may suffer a loss of precision. That is, the format specifier that you're using to print a `sizeof`, `%d`, is not capable of printing the full range of `size_t`.  Change `%d` to `%zu` and your warning will go away.

Comment: It's actually not just a loss of precision, it's a possible segfault or stack overwrite. Passing a size_t on most 64-bit systems will push 8 bytes onto the stack whereas %d will read only 4 bytes. It's simply an accident that his program doesn't crash; the bottom 4 bytes of the 8 bytes pushed happened to contain the right value (may not be the case on a big-endian system) and printf didn't read any more bytes afterwards.

Comment: Unknown conversion z.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem in Linux. the same program runs without error in windows (means '%d' worked without error), but for linux i had to replace all the '%d' with'%lu' to run the program.