# Use of unsigned int in different cases?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I want to ask what is the difference between these two cases ?

**Case1:**

```
unsigned int i;
for(i=10;i>=0;i--)
printf("%d",i);
```

It will result in an infinite loop!

**Case2:**

```
unsigned int a=-5;
printf("%d",a);
```

It will print -5 on the screen.

Now the reason for case 1 is that `i` is declared as `unsigned int` so it **can not take negative** **values**,hence will always be greater than 0.

But in case 2, if `a` cannot take negative values, why **-5 is being printed**???

What is the difference between these two cases?

Comment: You told `printf` to interpret `a` as a signed integer, and so it did.

Comment: `"%d"`.... do you want `"%u"`?

Comment: It is undefined behavior to [incorrectly specificity the argument to printf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21128106/1708801).

Comment: +1 because I have the same doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `i` is declared unsigned so it can not take negative values

That is correct. Most optimizing compilers will notice that, drop the condition from the loop, and issue a warning.

> In case 2, if a can not take negative values, why -5 is being printed?

Because on your platform `int` and `unsigned int` have such a representation that assigning `-5` to `unsigned int` and then passing it to `printf` preserves the representation of `-5` in the form that lets `printf` produce the "correct" result.

This is true on your platform, but other platforms may be different. That is why the standard considers this behavior undefined (i.e. `printf` could produce any output at all). If you print using the unsigned format specifier, you will see a large positive number.

Comment: Can I ask,Why in the first case there is an infinite loop?

Comment: @Jerky Because unsigned numbers cannot go negative, so regardless of the value of `i` the condition `i >= 0` remains true.

Comment: Thank you sir, I got it now!

Answer (score 3):

When a -ve value is assigned to an `unsigned` variable, it can't hold that value and that value is added to `UINT_MAX` and finally you get a positive value.
Note that using wrong specifier to print a data type invokes **undefined behavior**.
See **C11: 7.21.6 p(6):**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup>

```
unsigned int a=-5;
printf("%u",a);  // use %u to print unsigned
```

will print the value of `UINT_MAX - 5`.

Comment: it's `UINT_MAX` instead of `UMAX_INT`

Answer (score 3):

The **difference** is that you are printing `a` as a signed integer.

```
printf("%d",a);
```

so while a may be unsigned, then the `%d` is asking to print the binary value as a signed value.   If you want to print it as a unsigned value, then use

```
printf("%u",a);
```

Most compilers will warn you about incompatible use of of parameters to printf -- so you could probably catch this by looking at all the warnings and fix it.