# How can I change this code, to it doesn´t give warnings of unsigned when compiling

Tags: c, warnings, unsigned

This program gives warnings when I try to compile it it says long unsigned int:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a;
    float b;
    double c;
    char d;

    printf("Size of int=%d bytes\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("Size of float=%d bytes\n",sizeof(b));
    printf("Size of double=%d bytes\n",sizeof(c));
    printf("Size of char=%d byte\n",sizeof(d));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` returns *size_t*, [the proper format specifier is zu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21128092/1708801), this is probably a dupliate

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour , That is an answer not a comment. Or should this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @CoolGuy no it is likely a duplicate but since I have dup hammer I won't vote to close a question as a duplicate of a question I have an answer on.

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked with no warnings.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour ,dup hammer means that you can close questions using just your close-vote,right(because you have the C gold badge?)?

Comment: @CoolGuy yes, that is correct but only in the case of duplicates.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? `gcc`?