# How and is the output of my code is 842?

Tags: c, sizeof, 32-bit, 16-bit

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
printf("%d\t",sizeof(6.5));
printf("%d\t",sizeof(90000));
printf("%d\t",sizeof('a'));

return 0;
}
```

When I'm compiling my code, the output will be: "842".
Can somebody explain why I get this output?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Note [sizeof returns size_t so you should use %zu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21128106/1708801).

Comment: Note that your code won't even compile as it stands, which makes me think it's not your actual code. Also I'd expect "8 4 1", unless your compiler has wide char support enabled.

Comment: @PaulR: I'd expect the last number to be "4", since `'a'` is (oddly enough) of type `int` (rather than `char` as one might reasonably suppose)...

Comment: @psmears: you may well be right - I think you get a different answer depending on whether you compile as C or C++ (`sizeof(int)` for C, `sizeof(char)` for C++) ?

Comment: @RobertWalton please copy and paste your real code instead of typing something out and getting it wrong

Comment: @RobertWalton It would help if you specify what platform and compiler you're using. Your output would be perfectly normal if you're on a platform with 8 byte doubles, 4 byte longs and 2 byte ints.

Comment: @PaulR: Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all syntax error in your code

```
printf("%d\t";sizeof('a'));
```

change this to

```
printf("%zu\t",sizeof('a'));   //note the change in format specifier also
             ^
             |
            see here
```

Then, <sup>assuming your platfrom is 32-bit</sup>

- `sizeof(6.5)` == `sizeof(double)` == 8
- `sizeof(90000)` == `sizeof(int)` == 4
- `sizeof('a')` == `sizeof(int)` == 4

To clarify, `a` represents a *value* of 97 which defaults to `int`. so, `sizeof('a')` should give a value of 4, not 2 or 1.

---

Edit:

To add, you will get an output of `8  4  2`, if, in 16-bit arch

- `sizeof(6.5)` == `sizeof(double)` == 8
- `sizeof(90000)` == `sizeof(long)` == 4
- `sizeof('a')` == `sizeof(int)` == 2

Comment: The size of `int` is implementation-defined. It could be `2` on OP's system.

Comment: @MattMcNabb but it should not vary, right? So it should be either `822` or `844`, no way it ca be `842`, right?

Comment: @MattMcNabb However, added a note about platform dependency. Hope it is ok now?

Comment: @DilipKumar if you're on a platform with a 2 byte int, 90000 could be a long of 4 bytes.

Comment: @DilipKumar it can be 842. 90000 doesn't fit in a 16 bit type, so if int is a 16 bit type, then 90000 will be a long, which may be twice as big as an int.

Comment: @WernerHenze no, it's not.

Comment: @nos you're right, that's why i was explicit in mentioning `assuming your platfrom is 32-bit`

Comment: @ArunA.S IMO, the question is tagged `C`, so let's concentrate on `c` compilers only. BTW, it's not a good idea to compile `c` code with `c++` compiler and vice versa. :-)

Comment: As I noted in my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515695/how-and-is-the-output-of-my-code-is-842#comment47186773_29515695) using `%d` is incorrect and leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thank you. I somehow missed that part. Will update accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on a 32 bit compiler

```
printf("%d\t",sizeof(6.5));
```

`6.5` is a double, so `sizeof(double)` gives `8`.

```
printf("%d\t",sizeof(90000));
```

`90000` is an int ( or a long ), so `sizeof(int)` gives `4`.

```
printf("%d\t";sizeof('a'));
             ^
             you left a semicolon here, change it to a comma
```

`'a'` is converted to int, so `sizeof(int)` gives `4`.

So the actual output is

```
8     4      4
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/UXHOvD)

But , if you're on a 16 bit compiler, you will get

`sizeof(6.5)` = `sizeof(double)` = `8`
`sizeof(90000)` = `sizeof(long)` = `4`
`sizeof('a')` = `sizeof(int)` = `2`

So that would explain your output.

Comment: why not 8 4 4 ?? as it stands, `'a'` == 97 == `int`

Comment: Indeed the size of a char should be 1, it is curious that he's output is different

Comment: @CosminMihai nope. it's not a `char`.

Comment: `may consider`...can you please elaborate?

Comment: `'a'` is an `int`, there is no option for the compiler.

Comment: `"The compiler may consider 'a' as a char, int or long. "`  -> No it may not. It's an int, which is 4 in your case , though there's platforms where an int is not 4 bytes too. (Just make sure the code is compiled with a C compiler, the output would be different in a C++ compiler).

Comment: It is `90000`, not `9000`. This may either be `int` or `long` depending on the implementation.

Comment: @nos , you are correct. I was on a c++ compiler so it gave me 1. When I tried it on a C compiler, it gave me 4.

Comment: `6.5` is a double, not a float.